# Online RSS notifications via email

Tags: email, rss, notifications

I'm looking for an online RSS notifier that will send me an email when there is a specific text (like a location; "Tokyo") within a news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com) service. You can convert an RSS stimulus to a custom email, or you can use that same RSS data to stimulate other events (e.g., a Twitter posting) as an added bonus.